# Upgrade Old Debian OS

Tags: upgrade, debian, debian-installer

as of now I am a noob about this, and will be my very first time to upgrade an os, the problem is debian has a very old version:
    **SMP Debian 3.2.73-2+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux**, and it can't be reinstalled because there's important big files there that can't be backed up that easily, the only thing I could do is upgrade the os. what are the commands I need to be able to do this?

edit:
would apt-get update suffice in my situation? my version is 3.2 and I need to upgrade it to the latest which is 8.5.

Comment: This question is asking for opinions instead of concrete information. Please re-formulate your question to help us address a specific problem, and do some more research before asking. Attempt the install, it will probably work.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I have given you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the commands that should upgrade your Debian install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

EDIT: `apt-get update` would not take care of everything, because all that `apt-get update` does is pull new package definitions from the remote repositories.

Comment: will it automatically upgrade the os version to the latest?

Comment: or do I need to be aware of the release notes and packages.

Comment: @jane it should

Comment: so in that order I should update then? nothing relevant commands needed?

Comment: @jane this should be sufficient. if you are having problems after your upgrade, ask a new question & link it here, or modify your existing question with your new issues. this should work fine though.

Comment: Won't you have to change the `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @wb9688 not necessarily, depends on what is already there (if it is release-specific or `stable`/`testing`)